# how can we use startActivityforResult() for Email intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using intent for send email with attachment,it is work fine,i want to get this email intent result,i already used `startActivityforResult()`,but i can't get result for email intent,how can we use `startActivityforResult()` for Email intent?

Thanks All

Comment: G-mail API does not return any intent result and its resultCode is 0 even if the email is not sent. If you need a different API, you have to implement your own, e.g. https://www.edumobile.org/android/send-email-on-button-click-without-email-chooser/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't, this is not part of the API. It returns once you have pressed send button even if it is not sent

Comment: i want to delete attachment image in sdcard after sending email,how to perform this task,please give some tips for me...

Comment: I don't think there's any tip to do that, Email activities don't give any clue on when the e-mail was sent.

Comment: @ok fedj, i want to send email with attach image,that image did not stored in sdcard,how can i attach and send email to user?

Comment: @sivaraj, don't ask questions N times, you already posted this kind of question, so read answers ...

Comment: If you had access to the logs or processes, maybe you could deduce it from there that an email was sent?

Comment: Now this is an awful design flaw in Androids API. Can't be for security or privacy reasons as the only result would just be *if* the user pressed the "send" action in the email activity.

Answer (score -1):

There is no API like was suggested earlier. But...
there is a workaround, though. The best way would be to use `startActivityForResult()`, instead of `startActivity()` to start the email intent. 
Then your `onActivityResult` method should look like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if (requestCode == YOUR_REQUEST_CODE){
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
       //if data is not null, the user has clicked the send button
       //in his email application
     }

}
```

}

Remember that if you call `startActivityForResult()` from the fragment, always use your activity context, like `context.startActivityForResult()` and the `onActivityResult` method should be overridden in your host activity.

Comment: I only get RESULT_CANCELLED and data == null, no matter what I do (cancel or send).

Comment: Returns RESULT_CANCELLED with GMail / Android 8. In which environment did it work as described?

Answer (score -2):

You sort of can, but it's ugly and inelegant.  I'll work on smoothing this out.
The main problem:  After the email is sent you end up at a black screen with nothing but your app title at the top.

I'll do a 'hit enter to continue' or something if I have to.

Anyway:  First snippet from main class writes the report to sdcard, then calls the activity that will send email.

```
WriteReportToStorage();

Intent Emailreport = new Intent(bvsactivity.this, Emailreport.class);
startActivityForResult(Emailreport,emailreport_ran);
```

Next, over in the emailreport class we do the standard email+attachment sending code:

```
public class Emailreport extends Activity {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

final Intent email = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        email.setType("text/html

");
            email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
            email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body");
            email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:/" +      Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "//Report.html"));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Email:"));
        }
```

Lastly, back in your 'main' class, the onactivityresult that deletes the sdcard file:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // Actions based on which menu item we chose.
        if (requestCode == emailreport_ran) {boolean deleted = reportfile.delete(); emailreport_ran = 1;}
        }
 }
```

Comment: This gets a return from the activity, but with no confirmation on whether the email was sent or not. Not even on whether it was canceled straight away. The OP specifically said he/she already did that, ant wanted to get a valid resultCode instead.