# How to know that the email is sent or saved or discarded...?

Tags: android, email

I am starting email app with my content.

After user completes his action.

How to know the status. (Sent/Discarded/Saved to Draft).

Thanks in advance...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. There is no standardized intent returned by email apps in response to ACTION_SEND. The best way to do it would be to provide the form for creating the email yourself, and only send the intent off if the user chooses to actually send it. I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish, though.

Also see [How to wait for email intent to finish and get result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443148/how-to-wait-for-email-intent-to-finish-and-get-result) or [how can we use startActivityforResult() for Email intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778048/how-can-we-use-startactivityforresult-for-email-intent)